# PHP change .php file using PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to change some values from .PHP file using PHP.

Here is my `config.php` file

```
class Config {

    const name = "Jorge Scâus"
    const domain = 'domain.com';
    const year = '2019';
    const version = 175b.89;

}
```

and here is my `editor.php` file:

```
$fl='config.php'; 
$tmp = fopen($fl, "r");
$content=fread($tmp,filesize($fl));
fclose($tmp);

$content = preg_replace('/\const year=\'(.*?)\';/', 'const year=\'2050\';', $content);

$tmp =fopen($fl, "w");
fwrite($tmp, $content);
fclose($tmp);
```

I'm executing this code to change `const year` but nothing is changed! And there are no errors. What I'm doing wrong?

Can you help me?
Thank you.

Comment: You're stepping in dangerous territory here.  Consider using a structured data file format like JSON instead.

Comment: Why? I'll not edit critical data, like database. It's only to change year, developer name, website version, etc. Also, I'll filter all inputs too

Comment: You'll inevitably get it wrong.  What if you want to change code formats/styles some day?  Maybe you decide in the future to be consistent with your quotes for string literals, and now all your regex is broken.  Maybe you split the line across multiple and add some comments, and now all your regex is broken.  Perhaps some day you auto-generate this stuff based on data and someone names themselves `exec('something-evil')` and now you're totally hosed.  Attempting to do what you're doing is error prone at best, likely irresponsible, and is undoubtedly something you'll regret later.

Comment: If you did actually want to programmatically edit PHP code, you'd properly parse the PHP with a tokenizer of some kind.  http://php.net/manual/en/tokenizer.examples.php  This would be a giant hassle for what you need... which is a simple config file.